# Ruby | designing mathematics?

Tags: ruby, math, primes

**Situation:**

- I am writing a program to solve for primes. I need to solve problems to the tune of 4x^2+y^2=n, where n is a known variable.
- Yes, it has to be Ruby.
- I am comfortable with spending a lot of time on this project.
- I would, preferably, like to write the solving algorithm for the equations myself and incorporate it as part of this project.

**What I would really love:**

- If anyone can provide me with a link to a guide, website, or disambiguation regarding the construction of formal algorithms related specifically to solving algebraic equations, or provide me with information that seems to *you the reader* that it would help me in my quest.
- Please don't suggest I use another language. I would also appreciate if, before answering, you accept that I really, really want to do this. There is no scope or time constraint on this project, and it is not for profit. It is for my own education.

**Note:**

- I'm not directly opposed to implementing and using an already extant math library/module/something for Ruby, but the other way is preferable to me.

Closing comments:

The problem is that I know how to solve these equations by hand/with a calculator, but I'm not sure how to solve them in code.

Comment: I don't understand the first part of your situation:  do you mean you want to find solutions to equations such as 4x^2+y^2==n where n is prime or where x and y are prime ?  Or something else perhaps.

Comment: While I wouldn't dream, given your insistence, of suggesting you use a language other than Ruby, I hope you don't mind me asking *why* you are so set on it?

Comment: @Russell: I would use Ruby myself as well, I do pet projects in Ruby because I find it exceptional for prototyping. If a project turns serious, it is always possible to rewrite the heavy tasks in C (with RubyInline).

Comment: @High Performance Mark
None of those numbers in that equation are necessarily prime. It's an equation related to the sieve of Atkins, which was designed in 2004 as a faster descendant to the algorithm sieve of Eratosthenes, which solves for prime numbers between two given inputs.

Comment: @Russell
I'm set on Ruby because I'm exploring.I already know what lies in the east, so I'm heading west.

Comment: @karatedog + andrew don't get me wrong, I absolutely love Ruby. But one of the key things about exploring new languages (for me) is learning what kinds of problem they are best suited to - what they are better at doing than any other language - and I'm not sure mathematical algorithms and number-crunching is Ruby's strong point.

Comment: Its a quadratic Diophantine problem. Not a Pell equation, which typically has infinitely many solutions if any exist at all. Because the signs on the quadratic terms are the same, this has finitely many solutions at most.

Comment: What makes something like Python better at number crunching? The number of libraries available?

Comment: @Russell: "best suited to" IMHO does not mean "fast". Ruby is a good language because you can write short, readable, easily refactorable code that runs. Not always fast, but runs.

Comment: You need to study numerical methods.  Sieve of Eratosthenes for primes and root finding methods will suit those two problems well.

Comment: @MatheusMoreira: IMHO Python is not better at number crunching than Ruby, neither Python has primitives nor Ruby, which makes a simple FOR loop super slow. A simple, empty loop of 256 million cycle (16000x16000) is 35 seconds in Ruby. The same machine loops the same cycle BUT calculates a Mandelbrot set (as a bonus) in C in the same time.

Comment: @karatedog I wasn't suggesting speed as a reason not to use it. It depends if speed is a requirement. It's not a straight choice between Ruby and C though - you could look at Erlang, Haskell, R... where the advantage is in the ways you can express yourself rather than the speed. Seems a shame if the aim is exploration to limit yourself in this way.

Comment: There ain't many existing libraries for math/science/data in Ruby because everyone is focusing on web. That's one reason some people switched to Python. Try to do something serious. If you need help, let me know. I am also rewriting the matrix class in standard lib.

Comment: You can also get some C libraries because I think there must be some out there. Compile into a shared so file and wrap it up into a Ruby gem/lib

Comment: You guys that are missing a number crunching gem for Ruby could check out if NArray  does it for you. http://narray.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Related search terms: Pell-Fermat equation (not quite the kind you are interested in though, but def. related), algebraic rings, continued fraction expansions. There are a lot of books on the subject, and this is a very interesting topic **if** you have some time to devote to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it seems you are trying to implement the [Sieve of Atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin) then you are also probably aware that 4x^2+y^2=n is only the first of three equations. I don't want to spoil your fun and thus the below only implements that one. If you get stuck, just comment this answer and I will get back to you.

```
max = 100
primes = Array.new(max + 1) { false }
sqrt = Math.sqrt(max)
1.upto(sqrt) do |x|
  1.upto(sqrt) do |y|
    n = 4 * x**2 + y**2
    primes[n] ^= true if n <= max && (n % 12 == 1 || n % 12 == 5)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are implementing the Sieve of Atkin. In that case, you don't actually *solve* the equation. Look at the [original paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2004-73-246/S0025-5718-03-01501-1/S0025-5718-03-01501-1.pdf) for the actual algorithm.

Comment: Your question [Index shouldn't start new page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23870/6865) was migrated to another stackexchange site (tex.sx). Please register on that site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept/up-/down-vote answers or edit your question. And then [welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)